# Using a custom table/DAC in a generic inquiry in 2020R2

Tags: acumatica

I am upgrading a customization project from 2019R1 to 2020R2. I have several custom tables/DACs that I reference within generic inquiries. In 2019R1, I'm able to select from these and it works fine without error.

In 2020R2, an obsolete table error is raised for existing customizations and I'm not able to select new custom DACs at all.

[image: GI screenshot]

Is there an attribute or another way to suppress this error and allow visibility of new custom DACs so they can be used within generic inquiries?

Here is the code for my custom DAC:

```
namespace P1S
{
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [PXCacheName("P1S Shipment Serial Nbrs.")]
    public class PSSOShipSerialNbrs : PX.Data.IBqlTable
    {
        ... column definitions ...
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens after you delete the DAC inside the tables selection.  Then re-add the table using the same alias?

Comment: Still doesn't work. I am able to delete the table, but I cannot re-add it. It's not available in the selector's panel, even under the ALL RECORDS tab. If I type the table name manually, it says, Error: Table Name cannot be found in the system.

Comment: Have you unpublished all customs from your site & re-published your new packages?

Comment: Unpublishing all packages and then re-publishing did the trick. Doh! Should have thought to try that.

Comment: I would appreciate a thumbs-up to my comment, if it helped you

Answer (score 1):

Unpublishing all customizations and then re-publishing from the main Customization Project screen (SM.20.45.05) fixes the error. Custom DACs are also now visible in the table selector.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the application worked for me